# orbited twisted installation problems

Tags: python, twisted

i am geting folloing error when i am trying to start orbited server

```
C:\Python26\Scripts>orbited
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Scripts\orbited-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('orbited==0.7.9', 'console_scripts', 'orbited')()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\orbited-0.7.9-py2.6.egg\orbited\start.py",
 line 84, in main
    install = _import('twisted.internet.%sreactor.install' % reactor_name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\orbited-0.7.9-py2.6.egg\orbited\start.py",
 line 13, in _import
    return reduce(getattr, name.split('.')[1:], __import__(module_import))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\selectreactor.py", line 2
1, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 25, i
n <module>
    from twisted.internet import tcp, udp
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 78, in <mod
ule>
    from twisted.internet import defer, base, address
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 17, in <m
odule>
    from twisted.python import log, failure, lockfile
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\lockfile.py", line 28, in <
module>
    from win32api import OpenProcess
ImportError: No module named win32api

C:\Python26\Scripts>
```

i am using windows vista. i seacrche on net and found that i sholld copy 2 file in system32 , when i tried to do so i found that those files were already present there. But am still geting the errror.

how wold i install win32api on vista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by installing [the win32 extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). If you have done so already, this is probably a path issue.

Comment: i am using windows vista. i seacrche on net and found that i sholld copy 2 file in system32 , when i tried to do so i found that those files were already present there.